# confused by the description of numpy.linalg.lstsq

Tags: linear-algebra, python

When reading [the description of numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq), I saw the following statement:"the number of linearly independent rows of a can be less than, equal to, or greater than its number of linearly independent columns."

Given that the column rank should be the same as the row rank, how should I understand the statement, as it does not look correct to me?